# SQL Server 2008 Calculation Bug

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Here is the query i am running

```
Select (100/18)*18
```

The answer i get is 90. I have tried declaring each of the numbers as decimals also, and i get the value `100.0008`, but when i calculate with variables as floats the answer is correct at '100' so does anyone have any idea why SQL calculates like this?

Comment: [Operator Precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190276.aspx) Never assume the RDBMS has a bug.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because it will first evelute the paranthesis

So

```
Select (100/18)*18
```

will (100/18) = 5.555555 but it assume both number as int so it will cast the result as int so it will return 5

so now `5*18 = 90`

If you want the correct result do this instead `Select (100*18)/18`

Answer (score 2):

to get the desired result you should try something like this:

```
Select CEILING((100/18.0)*18)
```

when you do this,

```
Select (100/18)*18
```

sql server consider operation as integer division and take select 100/18 as 5 instaed of 5.55555....

Answer (score 1):

Try to express the numders ac decimal numbers

```
SELECT (100.0/18)*18
```

and

```
SELECT ROUND((100.0/18)*18,2)
```

...

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
select abs(18*100/18)
```

Comment: Although ABS may not be needed, this works because of default precedence (M, D, A, S). Why the negative vote?

Comment: abs here may not be needed, but when the data is changed. it is needed. according to the question, the answer is correct